# What is the size of GameCenter achievement images?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, achievements, game-center

So I want to incorporate GameCenter achievements in my game, but I have to supply images for each achievement for display in the GameCenter app. Apple isn't really clear about the required size. I've read online that they demand 512px images, but then they scale them down to something like 32px which makes it all blurry and/or pixelated.

There must be a better method. I've seen several apps now with crisp, clear achievement images. How do they do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems we don't have much choice. Apple doesn't accept images smaller than 512px. So we just have to create 512px en hope Apple will resize them well.

Comment: Currently: "A localized image that represents the achievement. The image must be a .jpeg, .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or .png file that is 512 x 512 or 1024 x 1024 pixels, at least 72 dpi, and in the RGB color space. This property is required."

Answer (score 2):

At this point of time the sizes must be 1024x1024 or 512x512 pixels, RGB color space, and at least 72 dpi.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW15

> A localized image that represents the achievement. The image must be a .jpeg, .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or .png file that is 512 x 512 or 1024 x 1024 pixels, at least 72 dpi, and in the RGB color space. This property is required.

I don't think you want to put anything else than 1024x1024 at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you submit them at 512 X 512, just like the app icons.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently as I tested the Game CEnter Achievement icons in my DEVICE, it seems the icon size is a bit BIGGER THAN 512px. I uploaded a 512px, but end up with a little bit white space all around inside the gamecenter achievement view. I suppose, 550px or bigger is the safe size to do.